# Double angle formula: $1-\cos \theta=2\sin^2(\theta/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$1-\cos \theta=2\sin^2(\theta/2)$$

I am sure that double angle formula was used here. I have found a list of double angle formula

[image]

But, I can't solve it anyway.

$$\cos(2u)=1-2\sin^2 u$$
$$1-\cos \theta$$ can't be transformed.

---

$$\cos \Bigl(2 \cdot \frac{\theta}{2}\Bigr) = 1- 2\sin^2\Bigl(\frac{\theta}{2}\Bigr)$$

Although, I can't find the value.

Comment: "$\cos(2u)=1-2\sin^2 u$" $-$ See what you get if you write that for $u=\theta/2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv No! Look I didn't find there's a positive 1 and $\sin$ is in negative

Comment: $A = 1 - B \;\iff\; 1 - A = B$

Comment: It seems that you're looking for explanation of this specific derivation - if that's the case, probably the tag ([tag:proof-explanation]) would be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$cos(\theta)=cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} -sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}
\\=1-sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} - sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}
\\=1-2sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Comment: Typing `$\sin\theta$`, `$\cos\theta$`, `$\tan\theta$`, `$\csc\theta$`, `$\sec\theta$`, `$\cot\theta$` yields $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\tan\theta$, $\csc\theta$, $\sec\theta$, $\cot\theta$, respectively.

Comment: thank you @N.F. Taussig

Answer (score 1):

The obvious candidate is
$$
\cos2u=1-2\sin^2u
$$
which is valid for *every* $u$. If you use $u=\theta/2$, then the formula reads
$$
\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}
$$
Now move terms around to get
$$
2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=1-\cos\theta
$$